# Converting this piece of code from Haskell to SML (catamorphism / fold)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, sml, fold, smlnj

I'm trying to translate this piece of code from Haskell to SML that will produce a higher-order function (the well-known foldr)

```
type List_alg x u = (u, x->u->u)
list_cata :: List_alg x u -> [x] -> u list_cata (a,f) = cata where
  cata[] =a
  cata (x:l) = f x (cata l)
```

So if we want to create a new function `prod` that will give us a product of all elements in the list we can create by:

```
prod = list_cata (1, (*))
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
type ('a, 'b) List_alg = 'b * ('a -> 'b -> 'b)

fun list_cata (a, f) List_alg: 'a list -> 'b = 
  let
  fun cata (xs: 'a list) : 'b  = 
      case xs of
      [] => a
    | x::xs => f x (cata xs)
  in
    cata
  end

val prod = list_cata (1, fn (x,y) => x*y)
```

While the list_cata function compiles it's the prod that's giving me the error. The errors so far I get are:

```
Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: [int ty] * ([* ty] * [* ty] -> [int ty] -> [int ty])
  operand:         [int ty] * ([* ty] * [* ty] -> [* ty])
  in expression:
    list_cata (1,(fn (<pat>,<pat>) => <exp> * <exp>))
```

I don't quite understand what is the problem here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your function as written takes a curried function `f`, but you're passing an uncurried version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error message

```ml
Error: operator and operand do not agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: [int ty] * ([* ty] * [* ty] -> [int ty] -> [int ty])
  operand:         [int ty] * ([* ty] * [* ty] -> [* ty])
  in expression:
    list_cata (1,(fn (<pat>,<pat>) => <exp> * <exp>))
```

because of the line

```ml
val prod = list_cata (1, fn (x,y) => x*y)
```

Specifically, the second element of the tuple you're passing is of, speaking loosely, type `[* ty] * [* ty] -> [* ty]`. In contrast you're expecting a type which is an instance of `'a -> 'b -> 'b` here. Thus, this arises because you're using an uncurried function where you want a curried one.

Suppose then we revise to

```ml
type ('a, 'b) List_alg = 'b * ('a -> 'b -> 'b)

fun list_cata (a, f) List_alg: 'a list -> 'b = 
  let
  fun cata (xs: 'a list) : 'b  = 
      case xs of
      [] => a
    | x::xs => f x (cata xs)
  in
    cata
  end

fun curry f a b = f (a, b)
val prod = list_cata (1, curry op*) (* like ( * ) in haskell *)
```

If you do this, you'll get a rather strange type for `prod`, probably not quite what you want. I'm not quite clear on how the type inference works here, although someone with more experience than I could comment, but to my understanding you end up with an issue having what you want to be a polymorphic function inside of a non-expansive expression (a `let` expression) and thus invoke SML's [value restriction](http://mlton.org/ValueRestriction).

I think you can simplify your code further by just pattern matching on the list instead of having a `fun` binding in a `let` like so

```ml
fun ('a, 'b) list_cata (f : 'a -> 'b -> 'b) (z : 'b) ([ ] : 'a list) : 'b = z
           | list_cata f z (x::xs) = f x (list_cata f z xs)

fun curry f a b = f (a, b)
val prod = list_cata (curry op*) 1
```

Comment: You're right that we're hitting the value restriction. The problem is just that `list_cata` is trying to take another argument called `List_alg` but doesn't use it anywhere in the function body. This can just be removed entirely, and then prod will have the correct type.

Comment: On your first revised `list_cata`, SML assigns the type `'a * ('b -> 'a -> 'a) -> 'c -> 'b list -> 'a`. Notice the erroneous `'c` type parameter for the extra argument ;)

Comment: Ah I had missed the fact that it wasn't even being used as a proper type annotation in the original! That explains the extra parameter I couldn't find the source of.